# What is the difference between these two sentence in meaning

Tags: meaning

1. Climate change is a phenonmenon that affects all people in the whole
   world
2. Climate change is a phenomenon affecting all people in the
   world

I guess the meaning difference is tiny, if so, what are they stressing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the difference between these two sentences:

- I eat meat.
- I am eating meat.

The first is a general statement. It means it is something I do, but not necessarily right now. The second very specifically means I am doing it right now.

"Climate change affects people" could mean that, at some point in everybody's lives, we will be affected by climate change. Or perhaps just that the *concept* of climate change is something that everybody should be concerned about because it could affect them in the future.

But "climate change *is affecting people*" means it is affecting them *right now*.

Comment: But the question isn't about _is affecting_: it's about the participial phrase _affecting_.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find a difference in meaning between the first (with a *that* clause) and the second (with a participial clause).